# Getting Error numeric or value error: character to number conversion error

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I am invoking a REST service from PL/SQL – make an HTTP POST request using UTL_HTTP in Oracle Database 12.2 but I am getting the error after executing the function "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error".

Function Body:

```
declare
 req utl_http.req;
 res utl_http.resp;
 url varchar2(4000) := 'http://localhost:9002/cinema';
 host varchar2(4000) := 'test.com';
 name varchar2(4000);
 buffer varchar2(4000); 
 content varchar2(4000) := '{"room":"'||p_room_id||'", "partySize":"'||p_party_Size||'"}';

begin
 req := utl_http.begin_request(url, 'POST',' HTTP/1.1', host);
 utl_http.set_header(req, 'user-agent', 'mozilla/4.0'); 
 utl_http.set_header(req, 'content-type', 'application/json'); 
 utl_http.set_header(req, 'Content-Length', length(content));

 utl_http.write_text(req, content);
 res := utl_http.get_response(req);
 -- process the response from the HTTP call
begin
 loop
  utl_http.read_line(res, buffer);
  dbms_output.put_line(buffer);
end loop;
utl_http.end_response(res);
exception
when utl_http.end_of_body 
then
  utl_http.end_response(res);
 end;
end;
```

**Error:**

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at line 11
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"

*Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
       occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
       assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
       attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
       declared NUMBER(2).
*Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
       that values do not violate constraints.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening here

```
utl_http.begin_request(url, 'POST',' HTTP/1.1', host);
```

Pass `null` instead of the 3rd and 4th params, which is the default value. Try and see if that works.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_http.htm#ARPLS71021

Take a look at the example in the above url for begin request.

```
****req := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST (url=>the_url, method=>'POST');****
UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER (r      =>  req, 
                 name   =>  'Content-Type',   
                 value  =>  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER (r      =>   req, 
                 name   =>   'Content-Length', 
                 value  =>'  <length of data posted in bytes>');
UTL_HTTP.WRITE_TEXT (r      =>   req, 
                 data   =>   'p1 = value1&p2=value2...');
resp := UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE 
                 (r     =>   req);
```